# How do I overcome MissingMethodException please. Am running out of ideas

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

Have a Solution with 2 Projects, Report and Web developed in .net core 2.1 using AlanJudenMvcReportViewer which is working ok on about a dozen SSRS server reports.
Decided to use Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant to migrate to net 5.0. Struck many errors which I have overcome with the exception of this one:

Running any report in net 5.0 now gives me 'Report failed to load, check report parameters' which is actually a 500 / internal server error:
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller.Json(System.Object, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings)'.

The error is occuring in ReportViewer.cshtml/viewReportPage at :  $.get("/Report/ViewReportPage/?reportPath=@Model.ReportPath.UrlEncode()&page=" + page + "&" + urlParams)

Some research gave me: https://github.com/alanjuden/MvcReportViewer/issues/92 (and others):

...  There are two solutions, one involves modifying the ReportController from Alan's code, and the other involves including a package reference and modifying your startup to instruct MVC to use Newtonsoft JSON.

Option #1: In MvcReportViewer/ReportController/ViewReportPage method, completely replace the following code

new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver() });

with... new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions());

Option #2: First add a package reference to your .csproj file for your project in the ItemGroup that contains your other package references...

Then, in your Startup.cs/ConfigureServices method, instruct MVC to use Newtonsoft JSON...   services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();....

Have tried Option #2 - no change, same error.
Dont know how to apply Option #1 as I dont see the code to replace (and that may be the problem).

Have seen reference to problems with using earlier version packages.As far as I can see I have updated all of mine.

The ReportController.cs I am using is :

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SSFA_Web.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace SSFA_Web.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ReportController : AlanJuden.MvcReportViewer.ReportController 
      {
        private readonly SSFA_SQLContext _context;

        public ReportController(SSFA_SQLContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        protected override ICredentials NetworkCredentials 
        { 
            get 
            {
                return new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Myusername", "Mypassword", "Mydomain"); 
            }
        }

        protected override System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType ClientCredentialType
        {
            get
            {
                return System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
            }
        }

        protected override string ReportServerUrl
        { 
            get 
            {
                return "http://MyReportServer directory"; 
            } 
        }

        protected override bool UseCustomReportImagePath { get { return true; } }

        protected override string ReportImagePath
        { 
            get 
            { 
                return "/Report/ReportImage/?originalPath={0}";
            } 
        }
                
        
        public ActionResult CalendarListing()
        {
            var model = this.GetReportViewerModel(Request);
            model.ReportPath = "/Reports/CalendarListing";
            
            return View("ReportViewer", model);
        }

    // etc
        
    }
}
```

The ReportViewer.cshtml is :

```
@model AlanJuden.MvcReportViewer.ReportViewerModel
@using AlanJuden.MvcReportViewer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ReportViewer";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>ReportViewer</h2>

@section AdditionalHeadContent {
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/select2.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/select2-bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/mvcreportviewer-bootstrap.css" />
    <style>
        .row {
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-right: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/select2.min.4.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.highlight-5.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                _initializeReportViewerControls();

                $('.FirstPage, .ViewReport, .Refresh').click(function () {
                    if (!$(this).attr('disabled')) {
                        viewReportPage(1);
                    }
                });

                $('.PreviousPage').click(function () {
                    if (!$(this).attr('disabled')) {
                        var page = parseInt($('#ReportViewerCurrentPage').val()) - 1;

                        viewReportPage(page);
                    }
                });

                $('.NextPage').click(function () {
                    if (!$(this).attr('disabled')) {
                        var page = parseInt($('#ReportViewerCurrentPage').val()) + 1;

                        viewReportPage(page);
                    }
                });

                $('.LastPage').click(function () {
                    if (!$(this).attr('disabled')) {
                        var page = parseInt($('#ReportViewerTotalPages').text());

                        viewReportPage(page);
                    }
                });

                $('#ReportViewerCurrentPage').change(function () {
                    var page = $(this).val();

                    viewReportPage(page);
                });

                $('.ExportXml, .ExportCsv, .ExportPdf, .ExportMhtml, .ExportExcelOpenXml, .ExportTiff, .ExportWordOpenXml').click(function () {
                    exportReport($(this));
                });

                $('#ReportViewerSearchText').on("keypress", function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        // Cancel the default action on keypress event
                        e.preventDefault();
                        findText();
                    }
                });

                $('.FindTextButton').click(function () {
                    findText();
                });

                $('.Print').click(function () {
                    printReport();
                });
            });

            function _initializeReportViewerControls() {
                $('select').select2();

                try {
                    ReportViewer_Register_OnChanges();
                } catch (e) { }
            }

            function reloadParameters() {
                var params = $('.ParametersContainer :input').serializeArray();
                var urlParams = $.param(params);

                showLoadingProgress("Updating Parameters...");

                $.get("/Report/ReloadParameters/?reportPath=@Model.ReportPath.UrlEncode()&" + urlParams).done(function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        $('.Parameters').html(data);
                        _initializeReportViewerControls();

                        if ($('.ReportViewerContent').find('div').length != 1) {
                            $('.ReportViewerContent').html('<div class="ReportViewerInformation">Please fill parameters and run the report...</div>');
                        }
                    }
                    hideLoadingProgress();
                });
            }

            function showLoadingProgress(message) {
                hideLoadingProgress();

                $('.ReportViewerContent').hide();
                $('.ReportViewerContentContainer').append('<div class="loadingContainer"><div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><h2><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh gly-spin"></i>' + message + '</h2></div></div>');
            }

            function hideLoadingProgress() {
                $('.loadingContainer').remove();
                $('.ReportViewerContent').show();
            }

            function printReport() {
                var params = $('.ParametersContainer :input').serializeArray();
                var urlParams = $.param(params);

                window.open("/Report/PrintReport/?reportPath=@Model.ReportPath.UrlEncode()&" + urlParams, "_blank");
            }

            function findText() {
                $('.ReportViewerContent').removeHighlight();
                var searchText = $("#ReportViewerSearchText").val();
                if (searchText != undefined && searchText != null && searchText != "") {
                    showLoadingProgress('Searching Report...');
                    var params = $('.ParametersContainer :input').serializeArray();
                    var urlParams = $.param(params);

                    var page = parseInt($('#ReportViewerCurrentPage').val());

                    $.get("/Report/FindStringInReport/?reportPath=@Model.ReportPath.UrlEncode()&page=" + page + "&searchText=" + searchText + "&" + urlParams).done(function (data) {
                        if (data > 0) {
                            viewReportPage(data, function () {
                                $('.ReportViewerContent').highlight(searchText);
                                hideLoadingProgress();
                            });
                        } else {
                            $('.ReportViewerContent').highlight(searchText, { wholeWord: false, ignoreCase: true, color: "#ffff00", bold: true });
                            hideLoadingProgress();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            function viewReportPage(page, afterReportLoadedCallback) {
                showLoadingProgress('Loading Report Page...');
                var params = $('.ParametersContainer :input').serializeArray();
                var urlParams = $.param(params);
                var totalPages = parseInt($('#ReportViewerTotalPages').text());

                if (page == undefined || page == null || page < 1) {
                    page = 1;
                } else if (page > totalPages) {
                    page = totalPages;
                }

                $.get("/Report/ViewReportPage/?reportPath=@Model.ReportPath.UrlEncode()&page=" + page + "&" + urlParams)
                    .done(function (data) {
                        updateReportContent(data);
                        hideLoadingProgress();

                        if (afterReportLoadedCallback && typeof (afterReportLoadedCallback) == "function") {
                            afterReportLoadedCallback();
                        }
                })
                    .fail(function (data) {
                        $('.ReportViewerContent').html("<div class='ReportViewerError'>Report failed to load, check report parameters...</div>");
                        hideLoadingProgress();
                });
            }

            function exportReport(element) {
                var params = $('.ParametersContainer :input').serializeArray();
                var urlParams = $.param(params);
                var format = $(element).attr('class').replace("Export", "");

                window.location.href = "/Report/ExportReport/?reportPath=@Model.ReportPath.UrlEncode()&format=" + format + "&" + urlParams;
            }

            function updateReportContent(data) {
                if (data != undefined && data != null) {
                    $('#ReportViewerCurrentPage').val(data.CurrentPage);
                    $('#ReportViewerTotalPages').text(data.TotalPages);
                    $('.ReportViewerContent').html($.parseHTML(data.Content));

                    if (data.TotalPages <= 1) {
                        $('.FirstPage').attr('disabled', true);
                        $('.PreviousPage').attr('disabled', true);
                        $('.NextPage').attr('disabled', true);
                        $('.LastPage').attr('disabled', true);
                    } else {
                        $('.FirstPage').attr('disabled', false);
                        $('.PreviousPage').attr('disabled', false);
                        $('.NextPage').attr('disabled', false);
                        $('.LastPage').attr('disabled', false);
                    }
                }
            }
    </script>
}

@section Content {
    @Html.RenderReportViewer(Model)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you resolve `"/Report/ViewReportPage/?reportPath=@Model.ReportPath.UrlEncode()&page=" + page + "&" + urlParams` to actual values and see what it looks like. I assume there is some bad data there that it doesn't like

Comment: Thanks Nick, have already done this (with about 30 different values). Still get exactly the same result.

Comment: So when you plug that URL directly into a browser, do you get a 500 error or does it work? I have used SSRS purely with the Web URL API. If you troubleshoot the Web URL API it may help you isolate the problem. It sounds like this is an old unsupported library. It's just using the Web URL API to render a report, then doing some trickery with it.

Comment: After logon, If I plug a URL direct to my 2.1 version it works. Same URL with converted 5.0 version gives 500 error.

Comment: If you plug a URL directly into a browser it doesn't know what .net version you are on. But anyway at least it sounds like it's a valid URL. When the URL's are resolved between versions, do they look identical?

Comment: Yes they look identical

Comment: It's wierd because you're getting a MVC error in some javascript code which doesn't make sense to me. Do you get the MVC error when you open the report viewer page, or when you click the button to run the report?

Comment: These are real time reports. When you click the button to run the report you trigger the opening of the report viewer and (should) show the report immediately (as per 2.1). Forgot to mention, even though the report doesnt show (and you get the error), if I then hit the export button on the Report Viewer, and select (say) pdf, it will export the report. IE It is coming straight from SSRS (so the URL is ok). It is only the Viewer giving the problem.

Comment: The viewer is just doing exactly what the export does, except that it plops it into a div. It doesn't even go back to MVC to do anything. To troubleshoot, I suggest you debug and step through the javascript code. Also use the network tab to understand what is happening. It actually seems like it's working but then it posts off to a controller and has an error. When you run the `$get` code what do you see in the network tab in the response area? is it successful?

Comment: Had already done that. When I run the $get code using F12 Developer Tools/network tab/body I get about 10 successful gets (mainly bootstrap gets) finishing with the 500 error message mentioned on the last step:  "http://keeper.shirefootball.com/Report/ViewReportPage/?reportPath=%2FReports%2FCalendarListing&page=1&NoCache=9%2F16%2F2021%203%3A39%3A20%20PM&ReportViewerEnablePaging=True"

Comment: Are you saying the GET to the ssrs server results in a 500? That's why I suggested you put the URL directly in the browser and confirm it works.  I'm troubleshooting by comments here, I'm not sure if I'm being very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: (Which I only partially understand)

Thanks to both @Nick.McDermaid and @JonasH for your help.

Went back to AlanJuden GitHub and found another Controller of his with a different Method for the ViewReportPage with reference to the code mentioned in Option #1.

Copied this into my Controller (with a few mods for errors and changes for System.Text.Json mentioned earlier as Option #1) to try and get System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions() working.

IE Added following to ReportController.cs before report ActionResults.

```
public new JsonResult ViewReportPage(string reportPath, int? page = 0)
        {
            var model = this.GetReportViewerModel(Request);
            model.ViewMode = AlanJuden.MvcReportViewer.ReportViewModes.View;
            model.ReportPath = reportPath;

            var contentData = AlanJuden.MvcReportViewer.ReportServiceHelpers.ExportReportToFormat(model, AlanJuden.MvcReportViewer.ReportFormats.Html4_0, page, page);
            var content = model.Encoding.GetString(contentData.ReportData);
            if (model.UseCustomReportImagePath && model.ReportImagePath.HasValue())
            {
                content = AlanJuden.MvcReportViewer.ReportServiceHelpers.ReplaceImageUrls(model, content);
            }

            var jsonResult = Json(
                new
                {
                    contentData.CurrentPage,
                    Content = content,
                    contentData.TotalPages
                },
                
                new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions()); 

            return jsonResult;
        }
```

When I run this, at the $get code (F12 Developer Tools/network tab/body) I get a different 500 error - The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
SSFA_Web.Controllers.ReportController.ViewReportPage (SSFA_Web)
SSFA_Web.Controllers.ReportController.ViewReportPage (SSFA_Web)

I assume 1 from my Controller mods and 1 from AlanJudens dll.

Eventually (several days later) found that this works:

Changed ReportController.cs/JsonResult:
From    public new JsonResult ViewReportPage(string reportPath, int? page = 0)

To      public JsonResult ViewReportPageX(string reportPath, int? page = 0)

Changed ReportViewer.cshtml/viewReportPage
From    $.get("/Report/viewReportPage/?reportPath=@Model.ReportPath.UrlEncode()&page=" + page + "&" + urlParams)

To  $.get("/Report/viewReportPageX/?reportPath=@Model.ReportPath.UrlEncode()&page=" + page + "&" + urlParams)

Most probably not how it should be done but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is helpful, but the signature apparently have changed from

```
Json(Object, JsonSerializerSettings)
```

to

```
Json(Object, Object)
```

With the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.json?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Controller_Json_System_Object_System_Object_)

> ```
> data Object
> ```
>
> The object to serialize.
>
> ```
> serializerSettings  Object
> ```
>
> The serializer settings to be used by the formatter.
>
> When using System.Text.Json, this should be an instance of
> JsonSerializerOptions.
>
> When using Newtonsoft.Json, this should be an instance of
> JsonSerializerSettings.

So, presumably the method should still accept the same object. But if you have something that uses the old method signature you either need to update the reference, or need to update the library that calls that method. After all, method resolution happens when you compile the source code. When it reaches the jitter the method signatures need to match exactly.

I'm unfortunately not sufficient knowledagble about asp.net, nor .net core 2 vs .net 5 to provide more specific suggestions.

Comment: Thanks JonasH, had seen that reference previously in my research and like you dont have enough knowledge to apply it. Maybe what it means is that AlanJuden's package needs updating ?

Comment: @Rod Foulcher, That seems likely.